# making tabs closable from the third tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("#tabdiv").tabs("add","#bv-eng-p"+Counter ,"Tab-"+Counter);
```

I am using this to add new tabs. I need to make it closable only after the second tab. (first two tabs must not be closable). Once closed The last tab and tab content should be removed. Please Help!

Comment: What do you mean by closable? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery tabs-plugin doesn't directly support closable-tabs. What you can do is bind...

```
$("#tabdiv").tabs("remove", index );
```

...to some UI element inside (or outside) those tabs you want closable.

Comment: Here is the HTML sample
<div id="bv-hp-priority">   
    <div>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#bv-hp"><span>Static Tab</span></a></li>

    <li><a id="addTab" href="#" onclick="cloneDiv()"><span>+</span></a></li>
  </ul>
    <div id="bv-hp">
        </div>
        <div id="bv-p">
               <div id="bv-eng-media-image-p-img">    
                </div>    
          /*clicking this link should append another similar div with incremented id bv-eng-media-image-p-img1*/         
            <a href="#" id='bv-eng-add-media-image-p'>Add Image</a>            
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

Comment: jquery used
var bellPriorityCounter=0;
$("#bv-hp-priority").tabs();
});
 var PriorityCounter;
 function cloneDiv(){
 alert("called");
  PriorityCounter= ($('#bv-hp-priority').tabs( "length")-1);
 var newpriority=$("#bv-p").clone(true)
$('[id]').each(function() {
    this.id = this.id.replace(/\-p([\W_]|$)/, "-p" +PriorityCounter+"$1");
});
newpriority.css("display","block");
$('#bv-hp-priority').append(newpriority);
$("#bv-hp-priority").tabs("add","#bv-bell-p"+bellPriorityCounter ,"Priority-"+bellPriorityCounter);
 $('#bv-hp-priority').tabs({closable: true});
 }

Comment: rather than copy-pasting source code, use http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate a web-ui functionality

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rakeshradharamanan/NHMr9/2/ .. i am sorry i dont know how to inclute jqery ui and other external js in jsfiddle